# One big datasets or various subdatasets Jasper studio

Tags: dataset, jasper-reports

I am making a report that requires a complex query, the report has about 50 pages, and each page consists of a header and a table with around 30 rows.

The question is whether I should create a single dataset (Sql), even if you repeat the header information for each record, or is it better to create a dataset for the headers and a table to see the records of each header?

Which of the two options is more optimal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested with the software "Neor Profile Sql (Free)" and I have checked that when I run only one query I need less resources than when I run a query for each subdataset.

Thanks.